# What is the name for a group of five?

Tags: terminology

<sub>The title seems off-topic, and I don't know what to tag. Could anyone edit it?</sub>

I see group of four is quartet, three is trio, two is duo (?) and one is solo. I see every number has different name. So:

1. What is the name for five?
2. Is there any language of this naming because a friend of mine said that "try Latin, I think it's the language".

Comment: As in Schubert’s [Trout Quintet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trout_Quintet)? It must be one of the best known, quite likely _the_ best known piece for any quintet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The naming of groups does indeed come mostly from Latin, sometimes with Italian influence.
The etyomologies for the first nine are:

```
    Number    Group name     Latin      Italian      Meaning
      1         solo         solus       solo        "alone"
      2          duo           duo        due        "two" - this is the Latin word
      3         trio          tres        tre        "three" - tres, but on the pattern of duo
      4        quartet       quarto    quartetto     "fourth" (as opposed to "four")
      5        quintet       quintus    quinto       "fifth"
      6        sextet         sex        sei         "six" - from the Latin (old English: sestet)
      7        septet        septem     sette        "seven" 
      8         octet         octo       otto        "eight"
      9         nonet        novem       nove        "nine"
```

It is odd how 4 and 5 have their root in the ordinal number ("fourth, fifth") while the others count directly (two, three, six, etc). Also - the "-et" ending can have the connotation of "a piece written for..." (e.g. "duet").

Comment: I believe it's "O sole mio" where sole = sun.

Comment: @James - yes you are right. I shouldn't write answers at 2 am. What was I thinking- error removed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The Italian table is all mixed up: if you wanted to write the names of the numbers they are: *uno, due, tre, quattro, cinque, sei, sette, otto, nove*. If you wanted to write the names of the groups they are: *solo, duo, trio, quartetto, quintetto, sestetto, settetto, ottetto, nonetto*. If you wanted to write ordinal numbers then they would be: *primo, secondo, terzo, quarto, quinto, sesto, settimo, ottavo, nono*. Your table mixes all these three elements.

Comment: @Bakuriu - I am writing the etymology of each of the group names - sometimes these are numbers, sometimes ordinals, sometimes (as in "solo") neither. I am showing that most of the names can be traced to Latin, and that where the etymology is from the Italian, it's not always from a number. I am sorry if I did not make that clear - I do know how to count in Italian, but my point was (intended to be) that that doesn't always explain the names of the groups. Maybe I should make an additional column in my table - but then the description falls off the edge...

Comment: @Floris Well, I belive *trio* comes from Italian *trio* (see [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trio?s=t)) as *sextet* comes from *sestetto* (according to [this](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sestet), *not* from the latin number).

Comment: Trio comes actually from the prefix tri- which is used in greek and latin for many words even in english (trident, triangle, tridimensional etc.).
Just to cause some more confusion, a vocal trio is often called a terzetto.

Answer (score 11):

A quintet.

For example, the Miles Davis Quintet or the Charlie Parker Quintet with Dizzy Gillespie.

Johannes Brahms wrote a Piano Quintet in F minor, but no, it's not a piece for five pianos (it's for piano plus string quartet).

According to Merriam-Webster, the etymology of the word is Latin by way of Italian, from the Italian word "quintetto." First known use dates back to 1811.

Comment: Quint means five. Kwint is a fifth. Quintal harmonies are ones built on 5ths

Answer (score 8):

It is a [quintet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintet).

> A quintet is a group containing five members. It is commonly
>   associated with musical groups, such as a string quintet, or a group
>   of five singers, but can be applied to any situation where five
>   similar or related objects are considered a single unit. In classical
>   instrumental music, any additional instrument (such as a piano,
>   clarinet, oboe, etc.) joined to the usual string quartet (two violins,
>   a viola, and a cello), gives the resulting ensemble its name, such as
>   "piano quintet", "clarinet quintet", etc. A piece of music written for
>   such a group is similarly named.